# location request by iOS push notification (when the application is NOT running on backgorund)

Tags: ios, notifications, location, push

is it possible to send iOS push notification to get location when the application is not running in background? exactly as Find My iPhone do it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UIRemoteNotification** is your friend.

1) Register your app for Remote Push Notification:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:  UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                                        UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                                        UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

2) Implement the logic on applicationDidFinishLaunching (to handle push notifications arriving when the app is closed)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...

    if([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        //if we're here, apps was launched due to Remote Notification

    }

    //...
}
```

3) Implement the login on didReceiveRemoteNotification (to handle push notifications arriving when the app is running in foreground)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //...
    //business logic for GPS Position    
    //...
}
```

On step 2 and 3, implement your business logic to get the actual GPS position.

More info here on Apple Developer Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

Comment: Nice! In step 3, if the app is indeed running on background, can I use this function without open the app in fourground?

Comment: No. You can't. If you need to get the user position in background, you've to register your application as background location service.

Comment: it was very useful. unfortunatly I have no reputation to do that. many thanks.

Comment: Will the push notification still show as an alert when it arrives? Is there way to send hidden data and do not display an alert message?

Comment: @amarruffo take a look to this: http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/

Comment: "is it possible to send iOS push notification to get location when the application is not running in background?"

nobody answered this question

Answer (score 0):

When the app is running in the background, the only thing it can do with a push notification is to show a numeric badge, play a pre-packaged sound and/or display an alert. There is no code in your application that can be executed when the device receives push and your app is in the background.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not. Sorry. You can send a push notification requesting the user open the app and then the app can start getting their location.